# MongoDB Query by Key's value

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Is it possible to execute a query where you constrain it to a key's value? ex.

```
"1":{
     ...
    }
"2":{
     ...
    }
"3":{
     ...
    }
```

Execute a query where the keys value is less than 3 and greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are looking for $exists query. But it won't support the range existence.

```
db.testing.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51380b1838fa3b768b5aa6b6"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : "id1", "a" : 1, "b" : "abhishek", "c" : true }

db.testing.find({_id : { $exists :  1}, a : {$exists : 1} })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51380b1838fa3b768b5aa6b6"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "id1", "a" : 1, "b" : "abhishek", "c" : true }
```

Just FYI : I don't think these queries will use index, so will be very slow operation. Check the explain command below for $exists query.

```
db.testing.find({_id : { $exists :  1}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 3,
    "nscannedObjects" : 3,
    "nscanned" : 3,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "bdvlpabhishekk:27016"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb does not have a $between operator.

You will need to use $lt (less than, or $lte - less than equal to) and $gt (greater than or $gte - greater than equal to) to define the range you are looking for.
Something like this should work.

```
{
"_id" : {$gt : 1 , $lt : 3}
}
```